# What program/language can I use to handle large numbers (over 10^300)

Tags: computer-algebra

I'm trying to multiply together a set of numbers.

However, the programs I have tried (Excel, R, FreeMat) do not allow numbers above around 300 digits. This limits me to sets of a few hundred numbers at most.

What program can I use that isn't limited by the number of digits? And what size numbers can I realistically manipulate on a (high spec) home PC?

I'm not a programmer, however I can learn if this is the only way around it!

Comment: I think this might be more appropriate for mathstackexchange or csstackexchange?

Comment: Is there any popular programming language for which there isn't a package for larger integers? I doubt it. It's also an easy programming exercise to write your own if you don't care too much about speed. If you want arbitrary precision floating point arithmetic, that's only a little harder, and again there are many packages available in case you don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Every computer algebra system for symbolic manipulations, for example [Sage](http://sagemath.org) or [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/)
- Some programming languages have built-in support, for example Python, Haskell and Ruby
- [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) is a well-established library for C and C++

The size of numbers is limited by the memory of your PC (few GiB typically, thus a few billion digits are possible). Of course you should think about the question which kind of numbers you want to handle (integers, floating point numbers, fractions?).